# Subgroups of order $p^2$ of $Z_{p^2} \times Z_p$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

> How many subgroups of order $p^2$ does the group $Z_{p^2} \times Z_p$
> have?

Here $p$ is a prime and $Z_{k}$ is the cyclic group of order $k$ (NOT the $\mathbb{Z}_k = \mathbb{Z} / k\mathbb{Z}$). One should count the isomorphic subgroups separately.

I was able to determine the number of the elements of order $1,p$ and $p^2$, but I couldn't count the subgroups. Can anyone help me?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_k$ is $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$, though.

Comment: Yes, but $\mathbb{Z}_k$ is not always cyclic, while $Z_k$ is.

Comment: There is only one cyclic group of order $k$, and it's $\Bbb Z/k\Bbb Z$. The group $\Bbb Z_k$ always means either $\Bbb Z/k\Bbb Z$ or the $k$-adic integers. Assuming you're talking about finite groups here, $\Bbb Z_k$ is the exact same as $\Bbb Z/k\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @balkov $\mathbb{Z}_k$ is always cyclic, generated by the class of $1$.

Comment: There are two types of groups of order $p^2$: the cyclic group and the direct product of two cyclic groups.

Comment: Well, that's not true either, but okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $G=Z_{p^2}\times Z_p$, the order $p^2$ subgroups are kernels of nonzero homomorphisms
from $G$ to $Z_p$. Such a homomorphism maps $(a,b)$ to $(ta+ub)$ for some $t$, $u\in Z_p$
and so there are $p^2$ homomorphism, including the zero homomorphism
But not all non-zero homomorphisms have different kernels. Two have the
same kernel iff one is a multiple of the other. So there are $(p^2-1)/(p-1)=p+1$
subgroups of order $p^2$ in $G$.